# Why does a site suddenly thinks my network is compromised?

Tags: security, virus, captcha

I am on Debian 6 with all updates installed. I was trying to open a link from `archtecturelab.net`, when up pops this warning page (see below). What's going on? I don't have any windows machines on my network

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By network they mean a bigger network like a range within the ISP.

Just enter CAPTCHA to verify your intention is not to spam them, then you go ahead and browse the site.

Comment: Thanks, Tom. What does entering the captcha do? Is it possible that the very act of entering the captcha opens up vulnerabilities?

Comment: entering the captcha proves you are human. More or less, alot of them have been beaten at this point.

Comment: @user3671 - in some circumstances, yes, entering a captcha can assist a malicious attack (if the captcha request is actually being displayed by an attacker), however in this instance odds are in your favour that the Internet network block has been flagged as having compromised hosts so the captcha request is exactly as it says: an attempt to filter the humans from the bots.